# Application with scheduled notifications

Tags: android, android-notifications

I want to create an android application that sends notifications from time to time, (eg every 6 hours), and the user can interact with the notification to snooze it by 5 minutes or reschedule the following.

Concretely I want to know what kind of libraries or tools I'll need to use, to start searching information and learning about it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

AlarmManager is best suited for the activating your notification in a timed interval is your solution and i am afraid it he only solution

developer.android.com/reference/android/app/AlarmManager.html

And for the notification

developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/notifiers/notifications.html

How to build notification

developer.android.com/training/notify-user/build-notification.html

you can reschedule the the same alarm you set previously on accordance to the user interaction